# Google Universal Analytics Principal Domain Self Referral

Tags: google-analytics

I need help to solve that self referral scenario:

- Domain to exclude self referral:

  - example.com
- Domain to preserve referral:

  - alpha.example.com;
  - beta.example.com;
  - All subdomains.

With the configuration referral exclusion doesn't work. Have you a solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your own javascript function to check document.referrer before sending pageview and then:

1. Preserve referrer if contains subdomain etc.
2. Or set it empty if referral == 'example.com'

Docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#referrer I think it should work.

Or if you're using GTM check this: http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/implement-referral-exclusions-via-gtm/